# Callback not calling - jQuery/JS

Tags: jquery, callback

I'm trying to understand the callbacks but I am having trouble. I have the code below and the functions aren't calling in the right order. The alert is popping up before the piece is played on the board. I'm confused because when I put a break in the Chrome dev console I can step into the callback function and it works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var players = 0;
    var p1Piece = '';
    var moves = 0;
    var p1Wins = 0;
    var p2Wins = 0;
    var draws = 0;
    var question = $(".questions");
    var option1 = $(".one");
    var option2 = $(".two");
    var markerVal = '';
    var board = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'];
    var x = true;
    var cornerZero = $(".cornerZero");
    var edgeOne = $(".edgeOne");
    var cornerTwo = $(".cornerTwo");
    var edgeThree = $(".edgeThree");
    var center = $(".center");
    var edgeFive = $(".edgeFive");
    var cornerSix = $(".cornerSix");
    var edgeSeven = $(".edgeSeven");
    var cornerEight  =$(".cornerEight");

    $(".player").on("click", function() {
        //store number of players if first click, then change question to X or O
        if (players == 0) {
            players = $(this).text();
            option1.text("X");
            option2.text("O");
            $(".question").text("What will Player 1 play?");
        }
        //find which marker player 1 will be playing with
        else {
            markerVal = $(this).text();
            p1Piece = $(this).text();
            $(".question").css("display", "none");
            option1.css("display", "none");
            option2.css("display", "none")
            $(".board-holder").css("visibility", "visible");
            $(".player1").text("Player 1 wins: " + p1Wins);
            $(".draws").text("Draws: " + draws);

            if (players == 1) {
                $(".player2").text("Computer wins: " + p2Wins);

            }

            else {
                $(".player2").text("Player 2 wins: " + p2Wins);
            }
        }
    });

    cornerZero.on("click", function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("clickable")) {
            var temp = placeMarker(cornerZero, 0, boardAnalysis);
            $(this).removeClass("clickable");
        }

        else {
            return;
        }

    });

    edgeOne.on("click", function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("clickable")) {
            placeMarker(edgeOne, 1, boardAnalysis);
            $(this).removeClass("clickable");
        }

        else {
            return;
        }
    });

    cornerTwo.on("click", function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("clickable")) {
            placeMarker(cornerTwo, 2, boardAnalysis);
            $(this).removeClass("clickable");
        }

        else {
            return;
        }
    });

    edgeThree.on("click", function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("clickable")) {
            placeMarker(edgeThree, 3, boardAnalysis);
            $(this).removeClass("clickable");
        }

        else {
            return;
        }
    });

    center.on("click", function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("clickable")) {
            placeMarker(center, 4, boardAnalysis);
            $(this).removeClass("clickable");
        }

        else {
            return;
        }
    });

    edgeFive.on("click", function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("clickable")) {
            placeMarker(edgeFive, 5, boardAnalysis);
            $(this).removeClass("clickable");
        }

        else {
            return;
        }
    });

    cornerSix.on("click", function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("clickable")) {
            placeMarker(cornerSix, 6, boardAnalysis);
            $(this).removeClass("clickable");
        }

        else {
            return;
        }
    });

    edgeSeven.on("click", function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("clickable")) {
            placeMarker(edgeSeven, 7, boardAnalysis);
            $(this).removeClass("clickable");
        }

        else {
            return;
        }
    });

    cornerEight.on("click", function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("clickable")) {
            placeMarker(cornerEight, 8, boardAnalysis);
            $(this).removeClass("clickable");
        }

        else {
            return;
        }
    });

    function placeMarker(square, location, callback) {
        if (x) {
            square.html("<span class='marker'>X</span>");
            board[location] = 'X';
        }

        else {
            square.html("<span class='marker'>O</span>");
            board[location] = 'O';
        }

        x = !x;
        moves++;
        callback();
    }

    function boardAnalysis() {
        if (board[0] == board[1] && board[1] == board[2]) {
            newGame();
        }

        else if (board[0] == board[3] && board[3] == board[6]) {
            alert("winner");
            newGame();
        }

        else if (board[0] == board[4] && board[4] == board[8]) {
            alert("winner");
            newGame();
        }

        else if (board[1] == board[4] && board[4] == board[7]) {
            alert("winner");
            newGame();
        }

        else if (board[2] == board[5] && board[5] == board[8]) {
            alert("winner");
            newGame();
        }

        else if (board[2] == board[4] && board[4] == board[6]) {
            alert("winner");
            newGame();
        }

        else if (board[3] == board[4] && board[4] == board[5]) {
            alert("winner");
            newGame();
        }

        else if (board[6] == board[7] && board[7] == board[8]) {
            alert("winner");
            newGame();
        }

        else if (moves == 9) {
            alert("draw");
            newGame();
        }

        else {
            return;
        }
    }

    function newGame() {
        $("table.board td").html("");
        moves = 0;
        board = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'];

        $("td").each(function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass("clickable")) {

            }

            else {
                $(this).addClass("clickable");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: That's a lot of code, can you simplify the example?

Comment: Browsers don't render changes to the DOM until the Javascript returns, and that doesn't happen until after the alert.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. I'll keep working on it